# How to get instance of T of an Expression<Func<T, TK>>

Tags: c#, generics, expression

Is it possible to get the instance of `TModel` from `Expression` in the following method?

```
public void FooBar<TModel, TProperty> MyMethod(
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression) 
    where TModel : ViewModel
{
    ViewModel model = ???;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**There is no instance**, and as such there is no way to get the instance that doesn't exist.

The expression is merely an object that says, "If you give me a model, I know how to give you back a property of it."  It doesn't actually have a model until you give it a model.

Comment: **Bold makes everything more intense**

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is there a way to rebuild my expression that I have an instance in my method (actually I need just access to a string property of `ViewModel`).

Comment: You could pass your instance to your method?

Comment: @Rico You could change the expression to an `Expression<Func<TProperty>>` so that it doesn't accept any parameters, but then the caller would need to have access to a view model to create the appropriate expression.